# How to get all objects having the same max value with Java streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have players which have points. I want to get all the players who share the max amount of points using a stream and a filter.

```
public class Player {
    private int points; // Getter omitted
}
```

I can do this by first getting the player with the most points, and the filtering all players that have the same amount.

```
Player topPlayer = players.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Player::getPoints)).orElse(null);

players.stream().filter(p -> p.getPoints() == topPlayer.getPoints()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can this be done with a single predicate / single line ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could collect to a `TreeMap` first and only get the last entry (where the max is)

```
players.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           Player::getPoints,
           TreeMap::new,
           Collectors.toList()
       ))
       .lastEntry()
       .getValue();
```

Comment: Though the OP's original solution is more efficient in terms of complexity (O(n) vs. your O(nlogn)).

Comment: @Eran agreed. also the additional space...

Comment: It might be less efficient, but I could make good use of that TreeMap, because I must repeat my code for each group of points, actually.

Comment: I just tried your solution, but getLastEntry() is not public in TreeMap, is it ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Yotus my bad, it's actually `lastEntry`

Comment: You don't need to pass `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: @shmosel I think you do

Comment: You can do it in O(n): `players.stream() 
 .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getPoints), m -> Collections.max(m.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByKey())))  .getValue()`

Answer (score 6):

First group by the points and get a Map result,then find the max key in map. Time cost will be O(n):

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
players.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getPoints))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: you can simplify this with `Map::comparingByKey` btw

Comment: @Eugene thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that uses a custom collector. It is HUGE and ugly and complicated, but it runs in *O(n)*, only makes one pass over the data, and requires little extra space.

```
List<Player> highest = players.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, 
    (list, player) -> {
        if (list.isEmpty() || list.get(0).getPoints() == player.getPoints()) {
            list.add(player);
        } else if (list.get(0).getPoints() < player.getPoints()) {
            list.clear();
            list.add(player);
        }
    },
    (l1, l2) -> {
        if (l1.isEmpty()) {
            l1.addAll(l2);
        } else if (!l2.isEmpty()) {
            int cmp = Integer.compare(l1.get(0).getPoints(), l2.get(0).getPoints());
            if (cmp < 0) {
                l1.clear();
                l1.addAll(l2);
            } else if (cmp == 0) {
                l1.addAll(l2);
            }
        }
    });
```

The proof that the accumulator and combiner are associative is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

**EDIT:** I tried to write a prettier combiner. I managed to write a shorter and weirder. I believe it is the same as the one above:

```
(l1, l2) -> {
    int cmp = l1.stream().findAny().flatMap(p1 -> l2.stream().findAny().map(
            p2 -> Integer.compare(p1.getPoints(), p2.getPoints()))).orElse(0);
    if (cmp < 0) l1.clear();
    if (cmp <= 0) l1.addAll(l2);
}
```